# Java field hiding for attributes

Tags: java, field

I just started to learn Java, so please bear with me if the answer is somewhat obvious. I did some research but no avail.

From what I understand, attributes are not overriden but only field hidden. To determine whether the attribute in the superclass or the subclass is used, Java will check the type of the reference.

Then I don't under stand the output here:

```
public class Super {
    String str = "I'm super!\n";

    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    String str = "I'm sub.\n";
}

public class TestFH {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub s1 = new Sub();

        System.out.printf(s1.toString());
    }
}
```

It gives me:

```
I'm super!
```

I understand that I can achieve what I want easily via method overriding. I'm just curious about what's happenning under the hood.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you expect your output to be?

Comment: @RohitJain I was expecting "I'm sub.", since I'm invocking the method from a sub class reference (which is s1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call, `s1.toString()`, it's finding `toString()` method defined only in `Super` class hence using that method as super class methods are available in the sub class. **Your super class method `toString()` is using it's own class variable `str` (with value initialized in super class)** as the return value from the method and hence the behavior i.e. output as `I'm super!`.

If you want to get the output as `I'm sub.\n` then you need to reuse the same variable as in the super class and assign the new string value i.e. `I'm sub.\n` to it. Best option is to use constructors as:

```
  public class Super {
     String str = "I'm super!\n";

     public Super(String stringValue){
         this.str = stringValue;
     }

     public String toString() {
        return str;
     }
  }

  public class Sub extends Super {
     public Sub(){
       super("I'm sub.\n");
     }
  }

  public class TestFH {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Sub s1 = new Sub();
       System.out.printf(s1.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is what I want to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're hiding (shadowing) `str` in your child class. Since you have not overridden `toString()` in your child class, the call is being made in the parent class, and it sees the parent's `str`.

If you did this:

```
public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() {
        this.str = "I'm sub.\n";
    }
}
```

It would output what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This call is using the super class:

```
Sub s1 = new Sub();
System.out.printf(s1.toString());
```

The reason is that **Sub is not overriding** `str`, it is just declaring another variable that happens to have the same name. In other words, sub is just hiding the variable in `Super` (data members are not polymorphic).

You could give them different names if they mean different things. Or maybe have the `Sub` access (or modify) the parent's attribute using a getter method.

Comment: So whenever I invoke methods defined in superclass, it will use superclass's fields, not subclass's fields?

Answer (score 1):

you're not assigning the string literal, `"I'm sub.\n"` to the shared superclass field, you're creating a field local to the subclass and assigning it to that instead.

for example,

```
public class EncapsulationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MySuperObject obj = new MySubObject();

        System.out.println(obj); // prints I'm sub.
    }

    private static class MySuperObject{
        String str = "I'm super."; // protected, can be accessed directly 
                                   // by subclasses

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return str;
        }
    }

    private static class MySubObject extends MySuperObject{
        MySubObject(){
            super();
            str = "I'm sub."; // assign to superclass field
        }
    }
}
```

for more information, please see [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).