# Against what Java hiding warning safeguards us?

Tags: java

There is java compiler hiding rule that states "is hiding a field". I was wandering against what it safeguards us. I tried but I could not find any reasonable justification for this one.

Do you know any situation where it could save us? Thank you for answers :)

Comment: You may have the same field declared twice, in a subclass and superclass.  The warning prevents you from accidentally using the wrong field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984472/java-field-hiding-for-attributes

Comment: @Steve Thank you, good example.

Comment: @hamena314 Not quite duplicate, this is only one case, while this warning can possibly have more applications.