# Java - attribute inheritance example

Tags: java, inheritance

I am puzzled by this inheritance example found in a quizz from a Coursera Java course:

- class B is a subclass of class A
- class B `getPrefix()` method overrides class' A method
- class B `number` attribute overrides class' A attribute

```
class ClassA {
    protected int number;

    public ClassA() {
        number = 20;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getPrefix() + ": " + number);
    }

    protected String getPrefix() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    protected int number = 10;

    protected String getPrefix() {
        return "B";
    }
}



public class Quizz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.print();

        ClassA ab = new ClassB();
        ab.print();

    }
}
```

When we run this program, the printed result is:

```
B: 20
B: 20
```

However, I was expecting this result instead:

```
B: 10
B: 10
```

Can you explain how come class A `number` attribute is printed, and not class `B`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can you explain how come class A number attribute is printed, and not class B?

`ClassB` does not inherit `ClassA.number` field, but rather *hides* it.

---

See:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the right terminology which helped me find other similar questions on SO, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984472/java-field-hiding-for-attributes

Comment: @Tanguy I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah so you can override a method from a super class but you cannot declare another class member with the same name. You're creating a new class member with the name number. It would only refer to 10, the value from the super class #number if you used super.number instead of this.number.